# Groovy character literal for annotation metadata?

Tags: java, groovy, annotations

I wanted to test my **Java** custom annotation in Groovy but did not manage it because of the char issue.

> Groovyc: Expected 'a' to be an inline constant of type char not a field expression in @MyAnnotation

I know that *char* in groovy is specified as

```groovy
'a' as char
```

My **Java** custom annotation

```java
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    char someChar() default '#';

}
```

Not working **Groovy** code

```groovy
class Foo {

    @MyAnnotation(someChar = 'a' as char)
    Object hoo

}
```

If you extract the char as a constant, it does not work either.

Comment: `char` has in Groovy language poor position, in most context dominant are form of `String`

Comment: It seems that it won't work without changing the type to `String` :/

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one... what I found to work was:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    char someChar() default ('#' as char);

}

@CompileStatic
class Foo {

    @MyAnnotation(someChar =( (char)'a'))
    Object hoo

}
```

where the importart parts are the `as char` in the annotation definition (unless that is Java not Groovy), the `char` cast in the annotation usage, not `as char` but a hard cast along with making that class `@CompileStatic`. This seems to work for me, but if you have access to the annotation code you could also just change it to a String as I think I had it working simpler with a String.

Comment: I have not highlighted enough that the code under the test is **Java**, the question edited.

Comment: I would think the usage part of my suggestion would still work. I will give it a try once I fire up my laptop.

Comment: Yes, my answer works even when the annotation class is Java and the Foo class is Groovy. Your IDE might not like it - IntelliJ has the `(char)'a'` flagged as an error, but it compiles fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am using IntellJ Idea 14.1.5, Java 1.8.0_45 64-Bit and Groovy 2.4.4 but unlike you, it does not compile for me.

Comment: Very odd - my specs are almost exactly the same as yours.