# Attribute 'requiredOptionMarker' should have type 'java.lang.Character'; but found type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: groovy, picocli

Running Script **FAILS** with **Groovy 3.0.19** but **PASSES** with **Groovy 4.0.15**

I'm trying to follow picocli documentation instructions specific to groovy scripts : [Section 30.1.2. Groovy Scripts](https://picocli.info/#_groovy_scripts)

There is a particular annotation named **Command** that has a **requiredOptionMarker** attribute. See [section 14.4.4. Required-Option Marker](https://picocli.info/#_required_option_marker)
requiredOptionMarker accepts a char.

In my script when I try to assign **'*'** to **requiredOptionMarker** my script fails to compile.

```
@Command(name = "sampleScript",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        requiredOptionMarker = '*')
```

I get error :

```
Attribute 'requiredOptionMarker' should have type 'java.lang.Character'; but found type 'java.lang.String' in @picocli.CommandLine$Command
 @ line 63, column 32.
           requiredOptionMarker = '*',
                                  ^

1 error
```

Tried various suggestions like `(char) '*'` , `'*' as char`. Nothing seems to work.

While searching for it the closest I got to is this jira ticket [GROOVY-3278](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3278)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1 : START**

Just in case any wants to play around, I have a MCVE at

https://github.com/akmalick/sample-picocli/blob/requiredOptionMarker/sample-picocli.groovy

The [master](https://github.com/akmalick/sample-picocli/tree/master) branch contains script that will **PASS**

The [requiredOptionMarker](https://github.com/akmalick/sample-picocli/tree/requiredOptionMarker) branch contains the script that recreates the issue and **FAILS** as it contains the `requiredOptionMarker = '*'`  change.

**EDIT 1 : END**

**EDIT 2 : START**

After taking care of the comma as in

```
sortOptions = false,
    requiredOptionMarker = ((char)'*') //---->>>>> This DOES"T WORK
```

running without compile tatic I get something like this

```
>groovy sample-picocli.groovy

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\ws\sample-picocli.groovy: 35: Expected '(char) *' to be an inline constant of type char in @picocli.CommandLine$Command
 @ line 35, column 32.
           requiredOptionMarker = ((char)'*') //---->>>>> This DOES"T WORK
                                  ^

C:\ws\picocli\sample-picocli.groovy: 35: Attribute 'requiredOptionMarker' should have type 'java.lang.Character'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @picocli.CommandLine$Command
 @ line 35, column 32.
           requiredOptionMarker = ((char)'*') //---->>>>> This DOES"T WORK
                                  ^

C:\ws\picocli\sample-picocli.groovy: 35: Expected '(char) *' to be an inline constant of type char in @picocli.CommandLine$Command
 @ line 35, column 32.
           requiredOptionMarker = ((char)'*') //---->>>>> This DOES"T WORK
                                  ^

C:\ws\picocli\sample-picocli.groovy: 35: Attribute 'requiredOptionMarker' should have type 'java.lang.Character'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @picocli.CommandLine$Command
 @ line 35, column 32.
           requiredOptionMarker = ((char)'*') //---->>>>> This DOES"T WORK
                                  ^

4 errors
```

**EDIT 2 : END**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the solution presented here?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020020/1446916

Basically do a hard cast in your script:

```
@Command(
       …
    requiredOptionMarker = ((char) '*'))
```

Note that you need brackets around the whole thing: `((char) '*')`, just `(char) '*'` may not work.

Comment: In general I fear that would not work unless using compile static. If I statically compile my script it fails with tons of compilation errors all either related to undeclared variable or cannot find matching method. Also my groovy script has no classes. I have updated my OP to add a MCVE script

Comment: In the GitHub project I notice that the comma between the preceding line and `requiredOptionMarker = '*'` is not at the end of the preceding line but at the beginning of the requiredOptionMarker line. Groovy often has issues with that. What errors are you seeing without compile static?

Comment: I have added details under section `EDIT 2`. However I would also like to share that [I just came to know](https://groovy-community.slack.com/archives/C2NEFCM55/p1699943325815879?thread_ts=1699810278.851429&cid=C2NEFCM55) that this is a [BUG](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9206)